# V-for from a nested array

Tags: html, arrays, vue.js

I'm starting with vue.js and I need to populate `select`s with `v-for` that are inside another `v-for`.

I was reading questions about this subject but could not find a way to make it works in my case.

I have a nested array (tours) with **title** and **description** and I have a `v-for` inside another one to populate a `select` with tours' title:

[image]

html:

```
<div class="row" id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in hosters" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
        <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>


        <div class="tour-options-select">
            <select id="select-suggestions" name="tour-options-dropdown" class="tour-options-dropdown">
                <option v-for="tour in tours">{{ tour.title }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

vue.js:

```
let app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    data: {
        city: 'mycity',
        hosters: null,
        tours: [],
        title: [],
    },

    created: function () {
        this.searchHoster()
    },
    methods: {
        searchHoster: function () {
            axios.post('searchHoster.php', { "city": this.city }).then((response) => {

            this.hosters = response.data.hosters;
            console.log(this.hosters);

            this.tours = this.hosters.map(res => res.tours);
            console.log(this.tours);

            this.title = this.tours.map(res => res.title);
            console.log(this.title);

            }).catch((error) => {

                console.log(error);

            });

        },

    }
})
```

I’m getting `undefined` in `console.log(this.title);` line so i tried to use:

```
this.title = response.data.hosters.map(hoster => hoster.tours).flat().map(item => item.title);
```

but it gives me a simple array with all the titles of all users. So, all selects are populated with the same titles for everyone. Any tip about how to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `tours` to `item.tours` on second v-for:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in hosters" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
    <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>

    <div class="tour-options-select">
        <select id="select-suggestions" name="tour-options-dropdown" class="tour-options-dropdown">
            <option v-for="tour in item.tours">{{ tour.title }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you man! I knew it could be easier than I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do not break out the various pieces of data you are interested in rendering.  Instead, render the inner portions using the index value from the outer v-for.  For example, assuming your data looks like the data you depicted, then...

```
V-for="item in data"
    Render host info using item.name, etc.
    v-for="tour in item.tours"
        Render title and description from tour.title, etc.
```

Much faster and easier.  I might also suggest using an accordion type control as well - render a table of all the tours, and allow user to select the desired row by check box (which would then display further details in a details area).  - that way they can see all the options easily.  Make the items collapsible using @click to toggle a boolean value which controls show=boolean on a nested div.

Good luck.

Comment: I agree. I just need more experience by the way hehe. Thank u man!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="tour-options-select">
            <select id="select-suggestions" name="tour-options-dropdown" class="tour-options-dropdown">
                <option v-for="tour in  ̶t̶o̶u̶r̶  item.tours">{{ tour.title }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Change the tours to item.tours

Since you are already iterating through the first v-for the context for the 2nd v-for is "item". and item.tours would give you the proper object to iterate over.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Sure I'll do it. Thanks for the input